# ¿Como cambiar el el tipo de dato de una columna en firebird 2.5?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

Buenos dias estoy usando firebird 2.5 y yo estoy tratando de cambiar el tipo de dato de una columna. Primero dropeo la constraint de PK, luego cambio el tipo de datos con el siguiente codigo:

```
ALTER TABLE CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS DROP CONSTRAINT PK_CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS;

ALTER TABLE CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS
ALTER COLUMN NUMEROMOVIMIENTO
TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION
```

Luego cuando intento agregar la constraint de nuevo:

```
ALTER TABLE CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS PRIMARY KEY (NUMEROMOVIMIENTO);
```

me salta el siguiente error:

> can't format message 13:393 -- message file C:\Windows\firebird.msg not found.
> unsuccessful metadata update.
> Column: NUMEROMOVIMIENTO not defined as NOT NULL - cannot be used in PRIMARY KEY constraint >definition.

Lo intento solucionar con el siguiente codigo:

```
ALTER TABLE CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS ALTER COLUMN NUMEROMOVIMIENTO DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS PRIMARY KEY (NUMEROMOVIMIENTO);
```

Y ahora me salta este error:

> can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\Windows\firebird.msg not found.
> Dynamic SQL Error.
> SQL error code = -104.
> Token unknown - line 1, column 70.
> DOUBLE.

No se que estoy haciendo mal, si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El dialecto SQL de Firebird 2.5 no soporta cambiar el atributo `not null` de una columna. Tienes las siguientes opciones:

- La más usada, que es la que menos me gusta, es cambiar el atributo en el diccionario de datos (OJO, que esto ya no te servirá en versiones posteriores de Firebird).

  ```sql
      update rdb$relation_fields
         set RDB$NULL_FLAG = 0
       where WHERE RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'NUMEROMOVIMIENTO' 
         and RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS';
  ```

  El motor, en este caso, no realizará ninguna verificación sobre los datos que ya existan en la tabla, es tu responsabilidad asegurarte que realmente no exista ningún dato con valor `null` en la columna al de realizar el cambio.

  No está de más advertirte que debes ser cuidadoso al tocar el diccionario de datos, pues esto puede corromper fácilmente tu base de datos.
- Crear una nueva columna, que tenga el atributo `not null`, y voltear a esta la información de la columna original. La secuencia vendría siendo algo como la siguiente:

  ```sql
  alter table CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS 
    add NUMEROMOVIMIENTO_TEMP double precision default 1 not null;
  commit;
  update CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS
     set NUMEROMOVIMIENTO_TEMP = NUMEROMOVIMIENTO; 
  commit;
  alter table CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS alter NUMEROMOVIMIENTO_TEMP drop default;
  commit;
  alter table CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS drop NUMEROMOVIMIENTO;
  commit;
  alter table CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADOS alter NUMEROMOVIMIENTO_TEMP to NUMEROMOVIMIENTO;
  commit;
  ```

  **Advertencia**: He escrito el código en el navegador, puede tener errores de sintaxis y puede que algún commit no sea necesario. Te recomiendo hacer una copia de seguridad al iniciar y asegurarte de comprender los pasos antes de intentarlo.

  **Explicación**: Creamos una columna temporal, con atributo `not null` y un default (de otro modo, no podríamos crear la columna `not null` en una tabla que ya tiene datos.  Luego pasamos la información de la columna original a la nueva columna, eliminamos el valor default de la nueva columna, eliminamos la columna vieja y renombramos la columna nueva.
- La última opción es crear un constraint de tipo `check` sobre la columna, para asegurarnos que no pueda tener valores null:

  ```sql
  alter table CABEZAMOVIMIENTOSEMPLEADO add constraint ck_MiCheck check (NUMEROMOVIMIENTO is not null);
  ```

Comment: Tampoco funciona, ahora me tira el error en TYPE

Comment: ¿Qué version de Firebird estás utilizando?

Comment: Firebird 2.5 y ibexpert como gestor.

Comment: @Franco, edité la respuesta para cubrir el caso de FB 2.5.